# Prove this Context-Free Grammar is Ambiguous

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars

so I have a problem on one of my computational structures final reviews, and I cannot seem to figure it out. It's been driving me crazy, so I would like to post it here for some insight.

*Prove that the following CFG is ambiguous.*

S-> begin A end

A-> A;A / a / S

Terminals: begin, end, ;, a.
Variables: S, A.

I cannot seem to find a string w such that w can be derived in more than one way through this CFG. Any ideas as to how I might tackle this?

Comment: Almost everything you can think of works. Check the rule $A \to A;A$. You have two options how to get to $A;A;A$ from there.

Comment: @PHPNick No; for ambiguity, only left-most derivations count.

Comment: Hint: When do you derive the first `a`?